# Redirecting subdomain without changing URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

wondering if you can help me with some .htaccess.

I want to have sub.example.com display data from example.com/sub without changing the URL :
ie. sub.example.com will stay sub.example.com although it is reading from example.com/sub

I have the following data in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://example.com/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I tried to change the [L,NC,QSA] to [P] but I get an error 403 - forbidden access.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want an internal redirect, so start with specifying a _path_ as the substitution, and not a full & absolute URL ...

Comment: When I placed an internal path, I got a 403 Forbidden Error. Should I change something else as well?

Comment: Check the error log, and maybe enable rewrite logging as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/sub/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Adding some explanation will be helpful to know what this part of the code does, also to avoid the risk of deletion.